# Replacing a string in nth line a file

Tags: bash, unix, replace, sed

Hi need to replace a string in file **only in nth line** of file

file1

```
  hi this is line 1
  hi this is line 2
  hi this is line 3
  hi this is line 4
```

I need to replace 'hi' only in line 2

experted as below

```
  hi this is line 1
  Hello this is line 2
  hi this is line 3
  hi this is line 4
```

I tried by creating a temp file

```
  sed -n 2p  file1 > temp1
  perl -pi -e 's/hi/Hello/g' temp1  \\I tried to replace temp1 with line 2 in file1
  sed -i  '2d' file1   \\after this I failed to insert temp1 as a 2nd line in file1
```

Help me to replace a string in file in Nth line(without temp file is preferred.. ).

Thank you

Comment: If you already could use perl then I would suggest: `my $i=0;while(<>){$i++; if($i==2){s/^hi/Hello/};print;}`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
sed -i '2s/hi/Hello/' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Above answer is correct, but I am tempted to put AWK variant just for reference.

```
awk 'NR==2{gsub("hi","Hello",$1)}; {print $0}' file > newfile
```